# How can I add a Google Map to a Shiny app when I have all elements defined in a ui.R file?

Tags: javascript, r, google-maps, shiny

I am in the process of porting a combined HTML/CSS/JavaScript app to Shiny for code maintenance reasons.  I am trying to minimize the amount of HTML in the final app, so having a custom HTML interface in a www folder is not an option.

Initializing the map works fine for the HTML/CSS/JavaScript app.  The map shows up on its own and the user can easily interact with it.  However loading the JavaScript with `tags$head(tags$script(src="initializeMap.js"))` in `ui.R` results in no displayed map.  My `ui.R` code has the following structure.  Note that `initializeMap.js` is in a `www` folder within the project:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src="initializeMap.js")),  # Initialize the Google Map
  includeScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"),
  includeScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"),
    h1("Where did you live on July 1, 2014?"),
     mainPanel(
   # Other stuff
)))
```

`initializeMap.js` initializes the Google map and controls some custom behavior, like only allowing a single marker at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I forgot to set up a map canvas.  Adding the line `tags$body(tags$div(id="map-canvas", style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"))` set up a visible map.